# getting JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set with hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, window

I  just downloaded hadoop and unzipped the file. but when I run hadoop version command from command prompt , I'm getting below error . I double check and JAVA_HOME is set to  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin" which looks ok to me .

```
C:\Users\shri-pc>hadoop version
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set.
       Please update C:\JAVA\hadoop-2.6.0\conf\hadoop-env.cmd
'-Xmx512m' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Output of java -version command is coming properly . Please advice .

```
C:\Users\shri-pc>java -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I would stop saying "I'm sure...".  Hadoop disagrees with you.  You'll make faster progress if you assume you've made a mistake and leave no stone unturned in finding it.  That fact that java.exe shows the right version isn't enough.  What is JAVA_HOME set to?  You can display it.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set to  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin" .

Comment: It should be without the `\bin`. Hadoop will look for java in `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java`, so if your JAVA_HOME already contains that `\bin`, then it'll be looking for `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\bin\java`, which obviously doesn't exist. (This is pretty standard for how JAVA_HOME is used)

Comment: yes , i was using without bin first but it was not working . I retried again with removing the bin and then closing and opening the command prompt but it is giving me same error .

Comment: Should be without the /bin.  Then add JAVA_HOME/bin to your PATH.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `JAVA_HOME` should not include `bin`. Change it from

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin"
```

to

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45"
```

And you can add it to your path (in Windows) like

```
set "PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
```

Comment: Yes Elliott , I have this change in place but I'm still getting the same error ..

Comment: It's Windows, you generally can't *change in place*. Try rebooting.

Answer (score 54):

Issue was with space in JAVA_HOME path . I change the path as below and it started working.

from -

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin"

to -

> "C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin"

.

Comment: My answer included `set "PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"` which is how you escape a space in the variable on Windows (from the command line). Using `~1` works if don't have 64-bit Windows and Java.

Comment: thanks Elliott . I've marked you answer as answer of this question . Just one suggestion - If you can put this as a note in your answer , then probably it will be helpful for new comer who see your answer . thanks a lot !!

Comment: I moved my Java folder to my C drive. The space was the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: Elliot got burnt.

Comment: Thank you, You saved a lot of time and effort...!

Comment: "C:\PROGRA~1\" is something very helpful for this sort of problem from this answer and thanks for that. Only issue I see here is for JAVA_HOME as @ElliottFrisch mentioned bin should not be part of the path. later one can append %JAVA_HOME%\bin in path, where bin makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

If your JAVA_HOME is `Program Files` then change it to `PROGRA~1` in JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Comment: This worked for me because, in my case, the problem was that the JAVA_HOME value could not contain blank spaces.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing the path from

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45`

to

`C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_45`.

Answer (score 1):

Space in the path will not work.
Simply remove any spaces in the path.

In my case it is working with:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_261
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it worked to go to the java path and convert it to the windows short name, as indicated in this picture:

https://www.joe0.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/word-image-30.png

from this site:

https://www.joe0.com/2017/02/02/how-to-install-a-hadoop-single-node-cluster-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

1)There should not be any spaces in your path.

2)While setting-up java environment variables, JAVA_HOME should not contain '/bin'. Java-path should not contain the '/bin'. Also, ensure that your Java-8 path is on the top of all java versions you have in your system.

3)The same path should be updated in your Hadoop environment variable set-up. That is in the Hadoop-env file--->near JAVA_HOME