# Problem installing mapr-client on Windows 10

Tags: mapr

Have a secure cluster, version 6.0.0.20171109191718.GA, and trying to install mapr-client on Windows 10 (from mapr docs here: https://mapr.com/docs/60/AdvancedInstallation/SettingUptheClient-windows.html). Seeing error when trying to run the configure.bat script:

```
C:\opt\mapr>server\configure.bat -N mycluster.cluster.local -c -secure -C node001:7222,node002:7222,node003:7222
Don't forget to copy conf\ssl_truststore from a server on your cluster.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
'-Xmx512m' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Ultimatley, trying to run a mapr data science refinery docker image on Windows (and assuming that need a mapr client on the host OS to get that working). Assistance or advice would be appreciated. Please let me know any logs or other info that would be helpful to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging, problem was found to be due to JAVA_HOME env variable containing spaces, was...

```
$ echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
```

Followed a post here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281439/8236733) to substitute `Program Files` with no-space equivalent `PROGRA~1`.

Can the create mapr ticket and test access via...

1. Copy the `ssl_truststore` file from the `/opt/mapr/conf` directory on the cluster to the `c:\opt\mapr\conf` directory on the client
2. Create a MapR ticket

   ```
   C:\opt\mapr>bin\maprlogin.bat password -user mapr -cluster <clustername>
   ```
3. Verify ticket content and test connectivity

   ```
   C:\opt\mapr>bin\maprlogin.bat print
   C:\opt\mapr>bin\maprlogin.bat authtest
   ```
4. List content of MapR FS

   ```
   C:\opt\mapr>hadoop\hadoop-2.7.0\bin\hadoop.cmd fs -ls /

   <should be able to see top level HDFS location>
   ```